# When is a Lebesgue integrable function a Riemann integrable function?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

When is a Lebesgue integrable function a Riemann integrable function ?

And if we have $f\in \mathcal{L}^1([0,1],\lambda)$, does it implies that $f$ is Riemann integrable, and why ?

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't.

It was proven by Lebesgue that a bounded function $f$ is Riemann integrable precisely when the set of points where $f$ is discontinuous has measure zero.

Comment: So in what case we can go from lebesgue inegral to reimann integral ? When do we have $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]}fd\lambda$ for a Lebesgue integrable function $f$

Comment: @AnasBOUALII Precisely when - as this answer says - the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero. Is there something unsatisfying about this?

Comment: But does every Lebesgue integrable function is a.e continious and bounded ?

Comment: No, of course not. In your setup, the function $1_{\mathbb Q}$, the characteristic of the rationals, is everywhere discontinuous. And $f(x)=\tfrac1{\sqrt x}\,1_{\mathbb Q}$ is unbounded, everywhere discontinuous, and still in $L^1[0,1]$.

Comment: @bof: yes. My example was about a Lebesgue measurable function which is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yes, sir I totally get your example. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is the [Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Theorem), which says that $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuity points is of measure zero.

Note that $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (the indicator of the rationals) is Lebesgue-integrable but not Riemann integrable.  On $[0,1]$ it is almost everywhere bounded but not continuous.  Here, the set of discontinuity points is of measure $1$.  So we cannot say anything about continuity and Lebesgue integrability (except that every continuous function on a set of finite measure is Lebesgue-integrable).